# reading 2 columns from txt file

Tags: c++

I'm writing an small program in C++ and have an input file and need to read line by line, there're 2 columns in file, string name and integer number. for example:

```
abad 34
alex 44
chris 12
```

I wrote such code:

```
ifstream input("file.txt");
int num;
string str;

while( getline( input, line ) ){
  istringstream sline( line );
  if( !(sline>>str>>num) ){
     //throw error
  }
  ...
}
```

I need to throw errors in cases:

if there's no number - only name is written e.g. `abad` (actually I'm getting error with my code),

if there's a name and no number, e.g.: `abad 34a`(letter a in `34a` is ignored and transferred to just 34 in my code while error should be triggered),

or if there're more than 2 columns e.g. `abad 34 45` (2nd number is ignored).

How to read correctly input data ( and without iterators )?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if( !(sline >> str >> num >> std::ws) || sline.peek() != EOF ) {
     //throw error
}
```

`std::ws` is a stream manipulator that extracts possible whitespace that follows `num`. Include `<iomanip>` for it. Next you check if peeking in the stream returns EOF. If it doesn't, you've got more input waiting and that's an error.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work, for `abad 34a` I still have no error and getting number 34

Comment: @Ir0nm Oops, my logic sucks :) should be `||` not `&&`. fixed.

Comment: Yes, you're right ) it works now and many thanks for elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: Keep on an `std::vector` all the strings read in each line, so that you are able to process them easier. Then, there are three cases:

- No number: vec.size( ) = 1.
- More than two strings: vec.size( ) > 2.
- Invalid number: not all of the digits of vec[ 1 ] are digits

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {
  fstream in( "input.txt", fstream::in );
  fstream out( "error.txt", fstream::out );

  string line;

  while( getline( in, line ) ) {
    vector< string > cmd;
    istringstream istr( line );
    string tmp;

    while( istr >> tmp ) {
      cmd.push_back( tmp );
    }

    if( cmd.size( ) == 1 ) // Case 1: the user has entered only the name
    {
      out << "Error: you should also enter a number after the name." << endl; // or whatever
      continue; // Because there is no number in the input, there is no need to proceed
    }
    else if( cmd.size( ) > 2 ) // Case 3: more than two numbers or names
    {
      out << "Error: you should enter only one name and one number." << endl;
    }

    // Case 2: the user has enetered a number like 32a

    string num = cmd[ 1 ];

    for( int i = 0; i < num.size( ); ++i ) {
      if( !isdigit( num[ i ] ) ) {
        out << "Error: the number should only consist of the characters from 1-9." << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**File: input.txt**

```
abad 34
alex 44
chris 12
abad
abad 24a
abad 24 25
```

**File: error.txt**

```
Error: you should also enter a number after the name.
Error: the number should only consist of the characters from 1-9.
Error: you should enter only one name and one number.
```